# Add Bootstrap DateRangePicker in Angular Ui-Grid headerCellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker, angular-ui-grid, daterangepicker

I'm trying to add a bootstrap DateRangePicker on my header template for Angular UI-Grid. I can see that the template is working properly because it shows the Bootstrap Icon. I do not want to use the native angular Type:'date'. I want to use a bootstrap date picker.

I have all the includes needed for this to show up.

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

This is my Template HTML

```
<!-- DatePickerTemplate HTML -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="DatePickerTemplate.html">
  <div ng-controller="DatePickerController">
    <div>Sent On</div>
      <div class="input-group date" datepicker-popup is-open="true"
       ng-model="COL_FIELD"  min-date="2010-01-01">
       <input class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

This is my UI Grid columnDefinitons:

```
{ name: 'Sent On', field: 'SentDateTime', enableCellEdit: false,
  allowCellFocus: false, type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"M-d-yy H:mm"',
  headerCellTemplate: 'DatePickerTemplate.html' }
```

This is my Directive

```
app.directive("filterDatePicker", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'DatePickerTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

I have an empty controller at the moment, what I want to do in the controller is get the dates I pick from the BootStrap DateRangePicker once it's working

Controller

```
app.controller('DatePickerController', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {
        // return date picked from bootstrap datepicker
    }
]);
```

[image: GridHeader]
When I click on the little menu box it doesn't do anything. I'm not getting any errors in the developer console either.

Here is a Plunker, you can see both Date columns, one on the left is native the one on the right should be bootstrap which is not working.

Can someone please give me an idea of where I'm going wrong. I can't get the BootStrap DatePicker to open. I really want to add a DateRangePicker not just a regular Bootstrap Date Picker.

[Date Filter Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ep0Giw69wKV2oP3zEii)

Comment: You're turning things around ;) "Can someone please create a plunker or give me an idea of where I'm going wrong" It's supposed to be: "Here's a Plunker so you can see that it's going wrong". Please take a few minutes and read this: [mcve]

Comment: I added a plunker per iH8 suggestion.

Comment: In the plunker, are the labels reversed? Isn't the bootstrap one that isn't working the third column, not the second (which is working)?

Comment: Thanks B.A. I fixed the labels, didn't realize that I posted them backwards.

Comment: Don't have time to work the problem out fully, but there were a number of problems in the plunker. [I forked it here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LZ2aj2kRmzOqSekOeHVp?p=preview), and you can click into the datepicker input and tab down and see the datepicker dropdown now. You were not injecting 'ui.bootstrap' into your module, for one thing, and then you need to [follow the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/#/datepicker) to get the datepicker to work. Also, you are calling ui-bootstrap 0.10.0 (docs only go back to 0.12.0)... would recommend upgrading to ^v1.0.0.

Comment: B.A. Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize that it was calling the wrong version of bootstrap. I'm doing this in a .Net MVC framework at work. I use NUGet to import all my dependencies. I am using the latest UI-Grid version, angular, and bootstrap. You can click on the button in your example. I just don't see the calendar popping up. That's been the issue since jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, using the latest versions of Angular (1.5.0), UI-Bootstrap (1.1.2) and UI-Grid (3.1.1) with correction of some mistakes you made. You forgot to inject the `ui.bootstrap` module into your application and you didn't add the `uib-datepicker-popup` directive to your HTML input element. Also you haven got direct access to scope from a custom template. You need to prefix `grid.appScope` to every property/method you want to access in your controller scope:

> You can use grid.appScope in your row template to access elements in your controller's scope.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates

Otherwise it "works", at least thus far that the popup opens on tab and when you click the button but it won't overlap the headercell which can possibly be solved with CSS, but i'll leave that to you to figure out. Hope this helps. Good luck with your project. Here's a working snippet:

```js
angular.module('App', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.grid'
]);

angular.module('App').controller('Controller', [
             '$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            columnDefs: [{
                field: 'date',
                filterHeaderTemplate: 'DatePicker.html'
            }]
        };
        
        $scope.datePicker = {
            opened: false,
            open: function () {
                $scope.datePicker.opened = true;
            }
        };

    }
]);
```

```css
#grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Angular 1.5.0</title>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.1.1/ui-grid.css" />
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.1.1/ui-grid.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="DatePicker.html">
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="grid.appScope.datePicker.value" is-open="grid.appScope.datePicker.opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="grid.appScope.datePicker.open()">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Controller">
        <div id="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just made revisions to the plunker. It's not working because I'm already using `appScopeProvide` in the `$scope.gridOptions` definition. Its there a way around this to get my modal to popup and the bootstrap calendar to work as well. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry, you can't change the context/topic of the entire question. Your question was about UI-bootstrap timepicker as header in UI-Grid. As is, i consider the question as anwered. I'de suggest you consider marking it as such. Or wait for a better answer. If you have a new question please post a new question with the right title/context/example. I'll be glad to help. Let's keep this usefull for future users.

Comment: I marked it as answer and I put a new question up with the right context. [Revised Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35628616/2926260?sgp=2)